# Simplenews get scheduled nodes

Tags: 7, nodes, emails

I am using [simplenews module](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiO0NbD4eLLAhUFA44KHbkcDg0QFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fsimplenews&usg=AFQjCNFz-bK_CjBh8e5DujVJ7g4vZLNq_Q) for sending newsletter and [simplenews scheduler](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQ0cDN4eLLAhUFBY4KHWifBcIQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fsimplenews_scheduler&usg=AFQjCNEl2bMxJIuwcm57LZNAZ893-rOiww&bvm=bv.117868183,d.c2E) for scheduling it. I want to differentiate scheduled nodes and non-scheduled nodes. How can I achieve it.